# Prove that a simple planar bipartite graph on $n$ nodes has at most $2n-4$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory

By simple I mean no loops or double edges.

Comment: @Ali:  Do you mean that the entire result is false or that it is false for some cases?

Comment: hmm...I got it out of Lovasz's Discrete Math text and have given it to my students for HW.  If you find a counter example, let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "no loops" in the case of a bipartite graph ?

Comment: Congratulations on putting in almost no effort into the question and still somehow getting 2 golden badges and half of the way to the “Good Question” Badge. I am positively surprised.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very standard result in graph theory.

**Theorem:** If a connected planar graph with more than $3$ vertices has no cycles of length $3$, then $e \le 2v-4$.

**Proof:** From Euler's formula, we have $v-e+f=2$. Since there are no cycles of length $3$, every face has degree $4$ or greater. From the handshaking lemma, we then have
$$4f \le \sum_{f\in F}\deg(f) = 2e$$
Substituting, we have
$$2 = v-e+f \le v-e+\frac{e}{2}$$
which is the required result.

Comment: It's easily overlooked that the proof really makes use of $v\ge3$.

Comment: nic eexplanation sir