# Prove that a bipartite planar graph has a vertex of degree at most 3

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

Exam preparation.

I'm a bit confused on where to start with this question. How could one approach this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are at most $3$ vertices in the graph, the degree of a vertex is at most $2$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455720/123852) shows that for a planar bipartite graph with $v > 3$ we have

$$ e \leq 2v - 4 \enspace, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*) $$

where $v$ is the number of vertices and $e$ is the number of edges.  The handshaking lemma says the sum of the degrees of all vertices is $2e$.  Hence if all vertices have degree at least $4$, $2e \geq 4v$, which contradicts $(*)$.

Comment: I think you might have read the question wrong. Not at most 3 vertices. But has a vertex which has a degree of at most 3

Comment: No, I understood perfectly.  The proof starts with a case split.  If there are at most three vertices, no problem: the degree of any vertex can't exceed two.  If, on the other hand, there are more than three vertices, we invoke a result that ultimately rests on Euler formula for planar graphs and quickly dispatch our proof obligation.

Comment: thanks for the clarification