# Explanation of proof for planar bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

I am supposed to prove that a bipartite planar graph has a vertex of degree at most 3.

I saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168203/prove-that-a-bipartite-planar-graph-has-a-vertex-of-degree-at-most-3). But I am little bit confused.

I do not understand the following part:

For planar bipartite graph with $v>3$ we have

$e≤2v−4$.

How do I know that the statement holds for bipartite graph?

Comment: Did you follow the link in that answer to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455690/prove-that-a-simple-planar-bipartite-graph-on-n-nodes-has-at-most-2n-4-edges/455720#455720), which proves that result?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, but I do not understand how this holds for bipartite graphs. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is it because graph does not contain cycle of lenght 3?

Comment: Yes, indirectly. That means that every cycle has length at least $4$, so every face has at least $4$ edges, and the sum of the edges of all of the faces is therefore at least $4f$. Each edge belongs to $2$ faces, however, so each edge is counted twice in that sum, meaning that the sum is equal to $2e$. Thus, $2e\ge 4f$, so $e\ge 2f$. The rest is just substituting into Euler’s formula.