# Number of faces in Bipartite simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

Prove that the number of faces of a simple bipartite graph on 3 vertices is 4 faces?

The number of edges in a planar bipartite graph of order $n$ is at most $2n-4$.
Proof: Let G be a planar bipartite graph with n vertices and m edges. Consider a planar embedding of $G$ . Since, $G$ is bipartite, $G$ has no cycle of length three. So, each face in the planar embedding contains at least four edges.

I tried to draw a bipartite graph where two vertices on the left connected to one vertex on the right. I can conclude that I have 3 faces, but the correct answer should be 4.

Comment: How do you get more than one face out of this? The graph you are describing only has two edges.

Comment: @MorganRodgersThis is exactly what the Doctor of the course wrote. Consider any planner drawing of G with faces F. Every face must have size at least 4 b/c G is simple graph and bipartite on at least 3 vertices.

Comment: I'm guessing you misunderstood something. Because any simple bipartite graph on *exactly* 3 vertices will have at most two edges, and exactly one face.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, The number of edges in a planar bipartite graph of order n is at most 2n-4.
Proof: Let G be a planar bipartite graph with n vertices and m edges. Consider a planar
embedding of G. Since, G is bipartite, G has no cycle of length three. So, each face in the
planar embedding contains at least four edges.

So you can see that each face has 4 edges, but the Doctor added on the paper for 3 vertices. I am not sure who is wrong and I don't think I deserve to be downvoted as this is not my mistake as a new comer to graph theory.

Comment: Each face must have at least 4 edges. And your planar graph of order 3 has at most $2\cdot 3 -4 = 2$ edges. So you do not have enough edges for any interior face. I downvoted because your wording was not clear, and I don't see how you can draw a bipartite graph on 3 vertices and conclude that you have 3 faces. But you have added more details so it is somewhat better now

Comment: @MorganRodgers, You can have a look at very similar question below. One commented that number 3 vertices is overlooked and it seems that this is a source of confusion. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455690/prove-that-a-simple-planar-bipartite-graph-on-n-nodes-has-at-most-2n-4-edges

Comment: By reading the comments, I think you are being confused with the *number* of faces vs. the *size* of faces? A simple bipartite graph on three vertices (and let's say it's connected, i.e. 2 edges) has exactly $1$ face of size $4$. This is the $``$outside face$"$. If you have less than $3$ vertices, what goes wrong? (Hint: what happens to the bound?)

Comment: @Hendrix, you saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: @Avra You're welcome :)